# How to keep track of props available to a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

After only using ReactJS for a few days I’m already having trouble keeping track of which props are available to my various components.

I’d rather not scroll up to where my component is being called each time I need to remind myself what properties are available.

Is there a particular method to do this you would recommend? Perhaps there’s an extension to Visual Studio Code (my preferred editor) that would help with this?

Comment: It is a good habit to use `propTypes` to type your props. Then you will be able to remember your props and their types or look through them at the bottom of your component. Take a look at [Typechecking with PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Comment: There is library :  pls check https://github.com/nytimes/react-tracking, if it helps

Comment: If you use Typescript and `.tsx` files you'll get code completion, refactoring etc.  It's a lot easier than you think to start using TS, just renaming the files and starting with the no implicit any will get you started.  And the bonus is that it's built into VS Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that just writing a comment at the top of the component/file is a good way to keep track of props. You have to remember to keep the comment updated as you add/remove props but I haven't seen any extension or library that provides this functionality.

Alternatively, you can use [propTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) to keep track of your props. You can then use something like the [React PropTypes Generate](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=suming.react-proptypes-generate) extension to automatically generate the propTypes for a given component.

If you're using propTypes, the [React PropTypes Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OfHumanBondage.react-proptypes-intellisense)  provides the available props as suggestions so you don't have to look at the `propTypes` yourself.

Comment: propTypes seems like the way to go, although it's a shame that they have to be below the class definition. I guess I can use comments as well. 

I can't seem to get the proptypes intellisense extension to work however. I'll need to keep looking into that as it looks pretty nifty.

Comment: Yea the propTypes being at the bottom wouldn't be as bad if the intellisense worked :/ Still better than swapping between files though. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can check what props are passed using `console.log(this.props)` or checking your component throught the devtools. However, if you want to take a look at your props without switching files, then a good approach is to type your props. This can be done using static typechecker such as [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.htmlhttps://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html), and this is one of the reason why such typechecking options are popular nowadays..

Perhaps the easiest way to have your props available in your file would to get in the habit of type checking your props using `PropTypes`. You can take a look at [Typechecking with PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

You can type your props at the bottom of your component, and take a look at what props you have available and their types. This will also help in debugging by giving helpful warnings in your browser console.

Answer (score 1):

[React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) is the extension you're looking for. You can scroll through components and see the props of each component:
[image: react dev tools]